# Issues when deploying with Struts 2 web app

Tags: struts2, xwork

I am facing this error when running a web app in the Container. Expecting some help on the right direction to approach this issue.

**Caused by:**

```
Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - bundleresource://16756.fwk1755001097:42/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/XXX/XXX/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/16756/29/bundlefile/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:205)
... 107 more
```

Comment: Do you have the struts2 jar twice in your classpath or did you copy the struts-default.xml to your webapp?  (OffTopic: the most recent version in 2.3.15.1 which has security fixes)

Comment: @tom 2.3.15.2, actually.

Comment: 2.3.15.2 has issues when you are using DMI, wait for 2.3.15.3 or use 2.3.15.1

Comment: Actually the issue is with `action:` not DMI.