# Struts 2 simple application from java brains

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, struts2

i am doing a tutorial in java brain now and i'm getting the an error i don't understand why i have this error because i follow the tutorial stop by stop any idea on the error is much appreciated my console returns an error like this

```
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo Fingerprint Reader\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo Fingerprint Reader\x86\;C:\ProgramData\Lenovo\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.5\;.
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleStruts2' did not find a matching property.
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SampleFinder' did not find a matching property.
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 840 ms
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: /struts-tags is already defined
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/mmanlapig/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SimpleStruts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/mmanlapig/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SimpleStruts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:226)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/mmanlapig/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SimpleStruts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:229)
    ... 19 more

Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/mmanlapig/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SimpleStruts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:502)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/mmanlapig/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SimpleStruts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/mmanlapig/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SimpleStruts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:226)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/mmanlapig/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SimpleStruts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:229)
    ... 19 more

Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/SimpleStruts2] startup failed due to previous errors
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: /struts-tags is already defined
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 26, 2013 2:02:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2615 ms
```

Comment: Are you running tomcat from eclipse? If so have you added the jars that you have downloaded into your project? you will have to right click your project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add jars

Comment: i did you will have to right click your project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> user Libraries. i also did the right click project -> deploy assembly -> add -> java build path entries. that is why i'm wondering what is my error do you think it has something to do with my eclipse server?

Comment: The stacktrace is saying class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar. Try to clean the project or there is some jar which also contains this ObjectFactory class. I guess its Xwork.XX.jar

Comment: @Mudit i see so same jar has the same class so it has conflict?so i should remove the other jars?these are my jars xwork-core-2.3.15.3.jar
struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
comons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar which do you is the jar that i need to remove

Comment: i think you have added the jar inside your tomcat as well as inside your project. because the last bit of the error says the jar is in /C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar - remove the jars in the tomcat lib folder that you have added (note that tomcat itself will have some jars).

Comment: @HakHak try to remove that xwork jar.

Comment: @ArvindSridharan you right i did try to put all those jars in tomcat itself because i thought it is necessary if i want to run it without using eclipse i'll try to remove them and i'll be back on you on that

Comment: @ArvindSridharan thanks mate your answer was great was able  to run my  program now..i more thing you know how to handle this one <"SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter">

Comment: @HakHak - how were you able to run the code if the struts filter was not starting. Are you still getting exceptions on startup of your tomcat?

Comment: @ArvindSridharan its an error from another program and i was able to run it thank you anyway..you did a great job explaining things to me hope others will be enlightened with your answer thank you

Comment: have put an answer taken from the comments for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the jar inside your tomcat as well as inside your project. because the last bit of the error says the jar is in

C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/lib/struts2-core‌​-2.3.15.3.jar.

Remove the jars in the tomcat lib folder that you have added (note that tomcat itself will have some jars).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981530/issues-when-deploying-with-struts-2-web-app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366799/struts2-error-when-deploying-unable-to-load-bean-type-classcom-opensymphony, etc. Searching for the error would have sufficed.